# Error: This fragment inner class should be static [ValidFragment]

Tags: android

why when I compile the project it works with no errors, but when I want to build the generated apk it gives me this error :

Error: This fragment inner class should be static [ValidFragment]

and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats lint error, you are probably building with gradle, to disable aborting on errors, add:

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
```

to build.gradle, or better fix problem in code. For more on this particular error read here: [Fragment inner class should be static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571010/fragment-inner-class-should-be-static)