# Android OnPreferenceClickListener

Tags: java, android, preferencefragment, onpreferenceclicklistener

I have an `Activity` that displays a settings menu using a `PreferenceFragment`. There is a method that passes a list of `Bean`s to the fragment so it can dynamically generate a list of `Preference`s that I want to act essentially like buttons. I'm trying to use the `OnPreferenceClickListener` to react to one of the Preferences being clicked, but I need to let the outermost Activity know about this. My code looks like this:

```
public class PairActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, fragment)
                .commit();
        ...
    }


    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        public void displayBeans(Collection<Bean> beans) {
            ...
            for(Bean bean : beans) {
                Preference pref = new Preference(getActivity());
                pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                        // want to let the Activity know something happened
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The comment shows where I want to reach the Activity from, but it's inside of an anonymous class inside a static class... What can I do to solve my issue?

Comment: It's possible to do `((PairActivity)SettingsFragment.this.getActivity())`, but I'm concerned about the possibility of something breaking somewhere in this line of code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

<strike>Make your `SettingsFragment` an **inner** class of `PairActivity`:</strike>

```
public class PairActivity extends Activity {

    public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    }

}
```

Then you can safely reference the activity with `PairActivity.this`.

**Edit:**

That's a nice answer you linked and it's indeed the proper way to use it like that. I didn't think about it.

Nevertheless when the fragment is attached to an activity you can reference it using `getActivity`. A fragment will definitely be attached to an activity if you call this method from inside of a clickListener so it's fine to do this:

```
public class PairActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, fragment)
                .commit();
        ...
    }


    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        public void displayBeans(Collection<Bean> beans) {
            ...
            for(Bean bean : beans) {
                Preference pref = new Preference(getActivity());
                pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                        PairActivity pairActivity = (PairActivity) getActivity();
                        // Do something with pairActivity instance
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

You just need to make sure that you don't attach your fragment to another activity as the cast `(PairActivity)` will throw an exception then.

Comment: I've tried this, and Android Studio flags this as a potential problem. There is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571010/fragment-inner-class-should-be-static) talking about why it shouldn't be done, but I'm a newbie so I don't understand much of it.