# fragment inner static class and gradle issues

Tags: android-dialogfragment, lint

Initially I was getting an error "This fragment inner class should be static" in the following code:

```
 public class Activity4 extends FragmentActivity {

    EditText mEdit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity4);
    }


    public void selectDate(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}

public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mEdit.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
}

//error was here at SelectDateFragment
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
    }
}
}
```

I tried to figure out the solution & read on some post here that its a lint error and can be resolved by adding this to the gradle file:

```
lintOptions {
abortOnError false
}
```

but when I did that, I get the message that "cannot resolve symbol getDefaultProguardFile". This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample.pat1"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

And the previous error "This fragment inner class should be static" still persists. Surprisingly the app works just fine despite all this.. but I would like to know where I'm going wrong.. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rewrite the communication mechanic, you can mark fragment as a valid manually:

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
```

More description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571010/fragment-inner-class-should-be-static#15576322)

P.S. Proguard - it's totally another issue.