# Kotlin Factory on Inner Nested Class

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to create a nested inner class in Kotlin with a companion object factory method (the equivalent of a static factory method in Java). Here's a simplified version of my code.

```
class OuterClass {

    var myData:List<MyData> = List<>() //gets populated elsewhere

    fun getItemFragment(position:Int) : Fragment() {
        return InnerClass.Factory.newInstance(position)
    }

    inner class InnerClass : Fragment() {

        companion object Factory {

            fun newInstance(position:Int) : InnerClass {
                var ic : InnerClass = InnerClass()
                var bundle:Bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putInt("index", position)
                ic.arguments = bundle
                return ic
            }

        }

        override fun onCreateView(inflater:LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup, savedInstanceState:Bundle): View? {
            //create and return view, omitted. Need access to myData
    }
}
```

The compilier highlights "companion", saying "Modifier companion is not applicable inside inner class" and it also highlights the InnerClass() call, saying "Expression is inaccessible from a nested class Factory", use "inner" keyword to make the class inner.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do here with the equivalent of a static factory method in Java?

Comment: You should never make a Fragment an inner class because it needs a zero-args constructor. More on that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571010/fragment-inner-class-should-be-static

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can have:

```
class OuterClass {
    fun getItemFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return InnerClass.Factory.newInstance(position)
    }

    class InnerClass : Fragment() {
        companion object Factory {
            fun newInstance(position: Int): InnerClass {
                var ic: InnerClass = InnerClass()
                return ic
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the following **will not compile** in Kotlin:

```
class Parent {
    inner class Nested {
        companion object Factory { 
        }
    }
}
```

For the same reasons the following **will not compile** in Java:

```
public class Parent {
    public class Nested {
        public static boolean create(){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The culprit here is that nested `inner` classes in Kotlin, as well as nested non static classes in Java **have an implicit reference to parent** class instance. Since Kotlin aims to be highly interoperable with Java it follows the same rule.

Please see following questions for more in-depth explanation:

- [Why does Java prohibit static fields in inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953530/why-does-java-prohibit-static-fields-in-inner-classes)
- [Why can't we have static method in a (non-static) inner class?
  up vote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975134/why-cant-we-have-static-method-in-a-non-static-inner-class)

Comment: You know what, that all makes sense. After posting the question, I thought it might also be a Java limitation. I'll just have to find a different approach. Thanks!

Comment: Think of it this way:  the inner class needs an owner, how would your static initializer know who the owner should be?  (the outer class)